# scroll horizontal bootstrap4

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Resulta que estoy haciendo una web con bootstrap4 pero al momento de poner un lorem*1000 para probar el fixed-top de el titulo, resulta que este texto me crea un scroll horizontal pero no se como eliminarlo, no pongo codigo por que es muy sencillo y considero que no hya nesecidad, pero adjunto fotos

[Imagen del navegador señalando el scroll no deseado](https://image.ibb.co/bCPRDn/Bootstrap4_Mozilla_Firefox_001.png)

[Fragmento del codigo por si lo quieren ver](https://image.ibb.co/i7Oa67/Selecci_n_001.png)

Comment: Bienvenido, te aconsejo que en vez de usar imagenes agregues tu codigo, y de ser posible lo hagas con la herramienta (control+m), de esa manera va a ser mas fácil que puedan ayudarte, por otro lado veo que en vez de crear divs estas creando "classes", algo muy extraño

Comment: Tienes razon jaja

Answer (score 0):

Una de las formas para poder hacer un scroll horizontal es la siguiente:

```
<html>
    <head>
    
        <style>
        img{max-width:100%;}
        body{width:100%;}
        #horizontal-scroll {
            display : inline-flex;
            padding:1px;
        }
        
        #main {
            overflow-x:scroll;
            width:100%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    
     <body>
    
        <section id="main">
        <div class="x_panel horizontal-scroll" style="height:auto;"></div>
        </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```